# Why are all my file uploads skipping the else if condition?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I have a function that checks to see what the file type is.  This time, I want to check for correct file and sufficient file size as well.  If the file extension's correct but the file size is greater than 10MB, then it should throw the `alert();` inside the `else if()` condition's block.  Instead, it's being skipped.

I'm testing it with .mov file that's 37.3MB

What am I doing wrong?

```
function fileValidationWinnerPhoto() {
    const realFileBtn = document.getElementById("real-file");
    let filePath = realFileBtn.value;
    let maxSize = 10485760;

    // Allowing file type
    let allowedExtensions = /(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.bmp|\.mov|\.MOV)$/i;

    if (!allowedExtensions.exec(filePath)) {
        alert('Invalid file type');
        realFileBtn.value = '';
        return false;
    } else if(allowedExtensions.exec(filePath) && realFileBtn.files[0].size > maxSize) {
        alert("You have the correct file type but your uploaded file is too large!  Try uploading a file that's less than 10MB!");
        return false;
    } else {
        console.log("file accepted");
        fileAcceptedFlag = true;
    }
    return filePath;
}
```

Comment: `> !maxSize` : are you sure about the "!" ???

Comment: @Pierre yeah I've removed that but it still skips the else if.  not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it does enter "else if" block, just checked [here](https://jsbin.com/vozasayera/edit?html,output).
Make sure your environment supports [File Api](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/)
The easiest way to do that is to check if FileReader exists for global object:

```
if (window.FileReader) {
 console.log('File API works');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`file.value` usually doesn't work, for security reasons. Use the new `fileinput.files`

To check the tile type:

```js
let file = realFileBtn.files[0];
let type = file.type; //returns the MIME Type

//Method 1
if(/(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.bmp|\.mov|\.MOV)$/i.test(file.type)) {
  //code here
}

//Method 2
let type2=file.type.split('/')[0];
if(type2=="video" || type2=="image") {
  //code here
}
```

To check the file size:

```
if(file.size<maxSize) {
  //code here
}
```

[See more on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList)

Comment: cool thanks!  `time.type`?  not understanding that part.  Also, I don't see that in the MDN doc :)

Comment: oops, i accidentally wrote `time.type` instead of `file.type`